# Why does Windows 7 connect only "partially" to a home wifi network?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-router, wireless-networking

I have a Belkin N150 router. Several Windows XP machines and one Ubuntu machine connect to it successfully.

The problem: A certain Windows 7 Home Premium  machine connects inconsistently.  (DW 1501 Wireless-N Half-Mini network card. There is also a Broadcom Virtual Wireless adapter, driver version 5.60.48.75).

Usually, the network utility says that it was able to achieve  only a partial connection. The network icon shows a connection, but nothing actually works, The troubleshooting utility says nothing.

This Windows 7 machine connects without problems to other wifi networks.
This happened with WPA/WPA-2 personal security.When I removed the password from the wifi router, other machines could connect with no password. But the  Windows 7 XP network utility now told me that the router had not been configured. If I tried to connect without configuring the router through the Windows 7 network utility, it again failed to connect properly. When I let Windows 7 configure the router, it assigned a random password -- and now the other machines could connect with that password, but the Windows 7 machine still achieved only a "partial" connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly this combination of network card and router are having trouble working together. That is not unheard of, and the first thing to try would be a firmware update for both the router and the network card. Why don't you post the Belkni model and the model of your computer and network card, and maybe we can go from there.

Comment: It's a Belkin N150. I'll find the info on the computer too.

Comment: Are you using the default Windows software, or are you using a Belkin application to build the connection?

Comment: DW 1501 Wireless-N Half-Mini network card. There is also a Broadcom Virtual Wireless adapter, driver version 5.60.48.75.

Comment: @goblinbox It is, as far as I know, the default Windows software.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a static IP address set on the Windows 7 computer? ON the same vein is the router's DHCP turned on?

Open the start menu and type "Network," click "Connect to a Network."

Right click your Wireless Connection and choose Properties.

Double click "Internet Protocol Version 4..."

If you have anything set in here, change the radio buttons to "Obtain ...  Automatically."

It may pay to have a look at that same place on the other PCs that connect without hassle. If they have a gateway and/or DNS set you'll need to apply similar settings to your Windows 7 machine.

Basically, if you have an IP address set that doesn't work with the IP address setup of your router it will connect but it won't be able to communicate with it properly (i.e. no network or internet access.)

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. Both the functioning XP and the problematic Win7 have IPv4 set to "Obtain ...automatically" for both settings.